# retaining stdin if script is run through pipe

Tags: shell, sh, stdin

I have the following script which is built to read in stdin and print it out:

```
#############
# myscript.sh
#############
#!/bin/sh
STDIN=$(less <&0 2>/dev/null)
echo $STDIN
```

This script works if run the "normal"/"expected" way:

```
echo Testing | ./myscript.sh 
Testing
```

However, I need to run it differently...i.e. storing the script in a variable and running it. But the problem is, when I do, i lose the stdin information.

```
[root@ip-test]# thescript=$(cat ./myscript.sh)
[root@ip-test]# 
[root@ip-test]# echo Testing | echo "${thescript}" | sh
## I get no response
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the script as a command line argument instead.

```
echo Testing | sh -c "$thescript"
```